# Can't seem to find the canvas slider anywhere?

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil

I've been following a blender tutorial, its literally my first time in this software. In the tutorial it mentions having a grease pencil object selected in order to see the Canvas slider option in your viewport overlays drop down menu. No matter what I do I can't seem to get this setting in my viewport overlay menu and so I'm inable to see the physical plane that im trying to draw on. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind showing screenshots of how it looks in your Blender vs. what you expect to see? As a beginner, I can only recommend you pay attention closely to what is shown in a tutorial. That already begins with which Blender version you are using and which one is in the tutorial. For example: As far as I know there is no _Canvas_ slider in the _Show Overlays_ menu anymore in version 4.0, but a separate _Grease Pencil_ menu next to the overlays. Up to version 3.6.5 this was integrated in the overlays.